# Identifier exepected

Tags: identifier, bluej

I keep getting the error message "identifyer expected" on this line: hk.guess(charToGuess);
what do I need to do to correct that?

I am creating a simple Hangman game and it is giving me a lot of trouble. I am very new at programming and I am starting to feel very over-whelmed by this project.

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.*; 
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class Hangman {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
    HangmanSession hangmanSession = new HangmanSession();
    hangmanSession.play();
    }

    private HiddenKeyword hiddenKeyword;
    private int triesNumber = 7;
    hiddenKeyword hk = new HiddenKeyword();
    hk.guess(charToGuess);
    private void printState() {
    System.out.print( "Hidden word : " );
    hiddenKeyword.print();
    System.out.print( "Tries left: " + triesNumber + "\n<guess letter:>" );
    }

    public void play() {
    boolean bool = true;
    while( true ) {
    bool = true;
    printState();
    System.out.println( "Try again, you've already used that letter " + char.class );
    bool = false;
    }
    if( bool ) {
    if( hiddenKeyword.guess( char.class ) ) {
    System.out.println( "YAY! you have found letter! " + ch );
    }
    else {
    triesNumber--;
    }
    if( triesNumber < 1 )
    gameOver();

    if( hiddenKeyword.found() )
    congratulations();
    }
    }        //end of bool
    public void congratulations() {
    System.out.println( "Congratulations " + player + ", you win!" );
    System.exit( 0 );
    }

    public void gameOver() {
    System.out.println( "Sorry " + player + ", you lost, but you can try again!" );
    System.exit( 0 );
    }
    private String fValue;
    private StringBuffer pValue;
    private int lfoundNumber = 0;
    public String words() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int random = r.nextInt(20)+1;
    }

    public boolean found() {
    System.out.println( "Letters found:" + lfoundNumber + "/" + fValue.length() );
    return ( lfoundNumber == fValue.length() );
    }

    public boolean guess( char c ) {
    int index = fValue.indexOf( c );
    if( index == -1 )
    return false;
    else {
    lfoundNumber = lfoundNumber + findOccurances( c );
    return true;
    }
    }

    private int findOccurances( char c ) {
    int idx = fValue.indexOf( c );
    pValue.setCharAt( idx, fValue.charAt( idx ) );
    int counter = 1;
    while( idx != -1 ) {
    int idxx = fValue.indexOf( c, idx + 1 );
    idx = idxx;
    if( idx != -1 ) {
    counter++;
    pValue.setCharAt( idx, fValue.charAt( idx ) );
    }
    }
    return counter;
    }

    public void print() {
    System.out.println( pValue );
    }
    private char[] lbox = new char[24];
    private int counter = 0;

    public boolean contains( char c ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < counter; i++ ) {
    if( lbox[i] == c )
    return true;
    }
    lbox[counter] = c;
    counter++;
    return false;
    }

    public void print() {
    System.out.print( "\nLetterBox:" );
    for( int i = 0; i < counter; i++ ) {
    System.out.print( lbox[i] );
    }
    System.out.println( "" );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int words = 20;String wordsString;
    switch(random) {
    case 1:
    return "star";

    case 2:
    return "hooray";

    case 3:
    return "dog";

    case 4:
    return "improvise";

    case 5: 
    return "teacher";

    case 6:
    return "college";

    case 7:
    return "seahawks";

    case 8:
    return "read";

    case 9:
    return "computer";

   case 10:
   return "program";

   case 11:
   return "holiday";

   case 12:
   return "film";

   case 13:
   return "music";

   case 14:
   return "learn";

   case 15: 
   return "library";

   case 16:
   return "waterfall";

   case 17:
   return "book";

   case 18:
   return "semester";

   case 19:
   return "first";

   case 20:
   return "vacation";

   default:
   return"";
   }

   }

   } 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, as a rule of thumb in Java, that a class may contain only fields and methods. Statements (except maybe those that initialize a field to a default value) can only be written inside methods.

With the above in mind, the problem is that you are simply invoking a method (`hk.guess(charToGuess)`) inside the class but not inside any method and that statement is not a field initializer.